# Extracting seprated code from a textfile and storing it into array for further usage

Tags: java, arrays

So i should read ID,UserName,Password from a textfile (They are seprated by "~!~") 1~!~Jhon~!~12345
       2~!~Mark~!~12345
       3~!~Linda~!~abcde
       4~!~Mary~!~qwerty
here is how the text file looks like, my code always prompts false even when my input is (1 Jhon 12345).

public boolean LoginAsAdmin (int myID,String myUserName,String myPassword) throws FileNotFoundException{

```
      File myFile = new File ("D:\\Java\\DATA.txt");
      Scanner Writer = new Scanner(myFile);
      int j = 0;
      while (Writer.hasNext()){
          Admin myAdmin1 = new Admin();
          String output = Writer.nextLine();
          StringTokenizer Data = new StringTokenizer(output,"~!~");
          if(
          myAdmin1.setID(Integer.parseInt((String) Data.nextToken()))&&
          myAdmin1.setUserName((String) Data.nextToken())&&
          myAdmin1.setPassword((String) Data.nextToken())){
                            myAdmin[j] = myAdmin1;


          }
           j++;
      }
     for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){

         if(myAdmin[i].getID() == myID && myAdmin[i].getUserName().equals(myUserName) && myAdmin[i].getPassword().equals(myPassword)){
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you see? Post that to get quicker response.

Comment: why on earth are your setters in a `if` statement - setters shouldn't return anything.  Why is your `Input` called `Writer`?  Where is `myAdmin[j]` defined and how would you know how big to make this array?

Comment: A `NullPointerException` can be thrown if you try to access an element that isn't initialized in the `myAdmin` array.

Comment: myAdmin is an array of [4] placed in a this class already initialized and naming my input writer is just plain stupid , forgot to change it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat so i removed the setters from the if statment and it ended up solving my error. but now even when i enter the data i have stored in my text file it returns false. when it shouldn't. any idea why ?

Comment: 1) why do you even need to store in the array?  2) I suggest that you use follow an example like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) for how to read in a text file.  3)  Maybe edit your question with your latest code, and maybe we can visit it again.

Comment: i need to store the data as an object in the array idk if there is a better way to do so. its just what i learnt @ScaryWombat

Comment: *idk if there is a better way to do so* as you code is not working I would say so, so see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to put `nextToken` with an `if` statement, as it will fail early if the first `test` is `false` - Also I not not sure why your `setters` are returning boolean values.

Firstly I suggest that you use a BufferedReader to read you lines from a text file - see https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/ for an example.

Then for each line do

```
String arr[] = inputStr.split("~!~");

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 3) {

    Admin myAdmin1 = new Admin ();
    String id = arr[i];
    myAdmin1.setId (id);
    String name = arr[i + 1];
    myAdmin1.setUsername (name);
    String passwd = arr[i + 2];
    myAdmin1.setPassword (passwd)
    myAdmin[i % 3] = myAdmin1;
    System.out.printf("%d %s %s%n", Integer.parseInt(id), name, passwd);

}
```